# How to make an @WebService spring aware

Tags: web-services, spring, jax-ws, autowired

I have a Web Service which I am trying to Autowire a variable into.  Here is the class:

```
package com.xetius.isales.pr7.service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.xetius.isales.pr7.domain.PR7Product;
import com.xetius.isales.pr7.domain.PR7Upgrade;
import com.xetius.isales.pr7.logic.UpgradeControllerInterface;

@WebService(serviceName="ProductRulesService",
            portName="ProductRulesPort",
            endpointInterface="com.xetius.isales.pr7.service.ProductRulesWebService",
            targetNamespace="http://pr7.isales.xetius.com")
public class ProductRulesWebService implements ProductRulesWebServiceInterface {

    @Autowired
    private UpgradeControllerInterface upgradeController;

    @Override
    public List<PR7Product> getProducts() {
        if (upgradeController == null) {
            return Arrays.asList(new PR7Product("Fail"));
        }
        return upgradeController.getProducts();
    }

    @Override
    public List<PR7Upgrade> getUpgrades() {
        if (upgradeController == null) {
            return Arrays.asList(new PR7Upgrade("Fail"));
        }
        return upgradeController.getUpgrades();
    }

    @Override
    public List<PR7Product> getProductsForUpgradeWithName(String upgradeName) {
        if (upgradeController == null) {
            return Arrays.asList(new PR7Product("Fail"));
        }
        return getProductsForUpgradeWithName(upgradeName);
    }

}
```

However, when I try to access the web service I am getting the Fail version returned, meaning that upgradeController is not being autowired.  Here is my applicationContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xetius.isales.pr7" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="upgradeController" class="com.xetius.isales.pr7.logic.UpgradeController" />

</beans>
```

How do I make it so that the @WebService class is spring aware and autowiring happens

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want autowiring to happen, *ProductRulesWebService* needs to extend *SpringBeanAutowiringSupport*

Extending that class will allow *UpgradeController* to be autowired

Answer (score 2):

Use a stack like CXF, which supports [Spring natively](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html), then you can essentially do something like this:

```
<bean id="aService" class="com.xetius.isales.pr7.service.ProductRulesWebService " />

<jaxws:endpoint id="aServiceEndpoint" implementor="#aService" address="/aService" />
```

Comment: This can also be done with Jersey: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104567/springjersey-transactional-annotation

Answer (score 1):

Depending on container version or even the Spring, hereinafter you will have an easy solution to expose your WSDL, use:

```
@PostConstruct
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```