# maven spring 3 hibernate4 No Session found for current thread hibernateexception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I have an maven spring 3 and hibernate 4 project as rest webservice.

I have converted the hibernate version from 3 to 4. With the version 3 is perfect running but in version 4 come the error when i fire the action to login in the system.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
    at de.decon.v5.core.dao.DaoAbstract.getObject(DaoAbstract.java:48)
    at de.decon.v5.core.controller.ApplicationController.applicationLogin(ApplicationController.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Jun 18, 2014 8:15:00 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
    at de.decon.v5.core.dao.DaoAbstract.getObject(DaoAbstract.java:48)
    at de.decon.v5.core.controller.ApplicationController.applicationLogin(ApplicationController.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jun 18, 2014 8:15:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Rest Service] in context with path [/deconFM_V5] threw exception
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
    at de.decon.v5.core.dao.DaoAbstract.getObject(DaoAbstract.java:48)
    at de.decon.v5.core.controller.ApplicationController.applicationLogin(ApplicationController.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd">

<!--        <context:annotation-config /> -->

        <context:component-scan base-package="de.decon.v5.core.controller" />

        <bean id="objectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"></bean>
        <bean id="jsonFactory" class="org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory"></bean>

        <bean id="appJsonMapper" class="de.decon.v5.core.json.mapper.ApplicationJson"></bean>

        <import resource="database/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
</beans>
```

This is the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:META-INF/spring/properties/database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
        p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
        p:acquireIncrement="5"
        p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
        p:maxPoolSize="100"
        p:maxStatements="50"
        p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="de.decon.v5.core.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userService" class="de.decon.v5.core.service.UserService"></bean>
    <bean id="userModel" class="de.decon.v5.core.model.UserModel" />
    <bean id="userDao" class="de.decon.v5.core.dao.UserDao" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>deconFmV5</groupId>
    <artifactId>deconFM_V5</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>deconFM_V5 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Components -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate / Datenbank Components -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.3.2.GA</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.4.0.GA</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Components -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey - Spmring Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log Components -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The ApplicationController.java with the login action

```
package de.decon.v5.core.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import de.decon.v5.core.dao.UserDao;
import de.decon.v5.core.json.mapper.ApplicationJson;
import de.decon.v5.core.model.UserModel;
import de.decon.v5.core.service.UserService;

/**
 * Application Controller �bernimmt das Login eines Benutzers und baut das Json Objekt f�r die gesamte Anwendung zusammen.
 * Interne Action Methoden Redirects arbeiten Schritt f�r Schritt die Anwendungsgenerierung zusammen.
 * Im letzten Schritt wird ein gro�es Json Objekt (String) an den Client ausgeliefert.
 * In diesem Objekt sind alle Men�s sowie Daten zum Benutzer geh�rend enthalten.
 * 
 */
@Path("/app")
@Component
public class ApplicationController 
{
    private static final String JSON_PATH = System.getProperty("wtp.deploy") + "\\deconFM_V5\\WEB-INF\\classes\\json\\";

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private JsonFactory jsonFactory;

    private JsonParser jsonParser;

    private JsonNode jsonNode;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationJson applicationJson;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public String applicationLogin(String input)
    {
        String loginState = "";
        String username = "";
        String passwd = "";

        try {
            jsonFactory = objectMapper.getJsonFactory();
            jsonParser = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(input);
            jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonParser);
            Iterator<JsonNode> itr = jsonNode.getElements();

            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                JsonNode elem = itr.next();
                String name = elem.get("name").toString().replace("\"", "");
                String value = elem.get("value").toString().replace("\"", "");

                if (name.equals("username")) {
                    username = elem.get("value").toString().replace("\"", "");
                }

                if (name.equals("userpass")) {
                    passwd = elem.get("value").toString().replace("\"", "");
                }
            }

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String bla = "from UserModel where username = '" + username + "' AND passwd = '" + passwd + "'";
        UserModel user = (UserModel) userService.getDao().getObject(bla);

        if (username.equals("a") && passwd.equals("a")) {
            loginState = "{\"state\" : true}";
        } else {
            loginState = "{\"state\" : false}";
        }

        return loginState;
    }
}
```

The DaoAbstract.java

```
package de.decon.v5.core.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;

public abstract class DaoAbstract implements DaoInterface
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save(Object obj) 
    {
        if (obj instanceof DaoInterface) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(obj);
        }
    }

    public void remove(Object obj) 
    {

        if (obj instanceof DaoInterface) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(obj);
        }
    }

    public Object getObject(Class daoClass, Serializable id) 
    {
        Object obj = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(daoClass, id);

        if (obj == null) {
            throw new ObjectRetrievalFailureException(daoClass, id);
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public Object getObject(String hql) 
    {
        List result = (List) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        Object obj = result.get(0);
        return obj;
    }

    public List getObjects(String hql) 
    {
        List result = (List) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        return result;
    }
}
```

UserService class

```
package de.decon.v5.core.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import de.decon.v5.core.dao.UserDao;
import de.decon.v5.core.model.UserModel;

public class UserService extends ServiceAbstract implements ServiceInterface {
    @Autowired
    UserModel userModel;
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    public UserModel getModel() {
        return userModel;
    }

    public UserDao getDao() {
        return userDao;
    }
}
```

Why comes the error by the login action?

I thank you all for the help.

Comment: Is the `getDao()` method annotated `@Transactional`

Comment: Annotate your dao with `@Transactional`.

Comment: <!--        <context:annotation-config /> --> uncomment this line to enable autowiring

Comment: I have write the @Transactional Annotaded in the UserDao Class but the error still comes.

Comment: Post the Service class, as well.

Comment: Sorry for unformated code but i can't write a awnswer because se set time limit.`package de.decon.v5.core.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import de.decon.v5.core.dao.UserDao;
import de.decon.v5.core.model.UserModel;

public class UserService extends ServiceAbstract implements ServiceInterface
{
 @Autowired
 UserModel userModel;
 
 @Autowired
 UserDao userDao;
 
 public UserModel getModel()
 {
  return userModel;
 }
 
 public UserDao getDao()
 {
  return userDao;
 }
}`

Comment: You should have added the class to your original post. I did that for you.

Comment: How did your application work before changing from Hibernate 3 to 4, because the code you posted shouldn't have worked. You have a transaction manager defined, but as it was mentioned above in comments, no method or class was marked as transactional. Also, did you uncomment `<context:annotation-config/>` because the `@Autowired` shouldn't have worked otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Transactions should go on service class.

Your service class is not annotated as a `@service`.

Your controller should be annotated with `@Controller`.

Comment: The OP uses Jersey. Things work a bit differently in this situation. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104567/springjersey-transactional-annotation).

Comment: @AndreiStefan its tagged spring-mvc

Comment: It is, but the stack trace says something else. Anyway, I do believe there is a lot of confusion in OP's post.