# @Autowired singleton of services is null in webservices object

Tags: java, spring

In my services project I have defined :

```
package fr.gipmds.fpoc.service;
@Service("FpocServices")
public class FpocServicesImpl implements FpocServices {
```

which implements

```
package fr.gipmds.fpoc.service;
@Service
public interface FpocServices {
```

In my webservice project I 've defined a webservice classes with an instance of this service :

```
package fr.gipmds.fpoc.controller.webservices.ficheparametrage.impl;

@WebService(serviceName = "PublierFicheParametrageService",
portName = "PublierFicheParametragePort",
targetNamespace = "http://ws.fpoc.gipmds.fr/",
endpointInterface = "fr.gipmds.fpoc.controller.webservices.ficheparametrage.PublierFicheParametrage")
public class PublierFicheParametrageImpl implements PublierFicheParametrage {
    @Autowired
    private FpocServices fpocServices;

    public Retour publier()  
      if (!fpocServices.existeFiche(idFiche)) {
```

In the parent project I also have :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.gipmds.fpoc"
    use-default-filters="true">
</context:component-scan>
```

But when I debug the code, fpocServices is still null. What did I forget to declare and/or instance?

Comment: Does spring scan for `@WebService`? If not, you'll need to add `@Component`.

Comment: I think this answer may help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5041311/2755755